# jQuery draggable: append to same position

Tags: jquery, append, jquery-ui-draggable

I am creating dynamic tables that get added when a user clicks a button.

```
 $('#addMenu').click(function(){
       var div = "<div>Some Data</div>";
       $('#dropbox').append(div);
 });
```

css

```
 #dropbox{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
 }
```

html

```
 <div id='dropbox'></div>   
 <input type='button' id='addMenu' value='addme'>
```

the append places the new div below where the last div was.  These divs are draggable, so there is no div in the dropbox anymore.  How can i append any new div to the same position in the dropbox div?

the fiddle (its ugly, but gets the point across)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mo6w30k2/1/)

1. click add menu.  (the word text appears in dropbox)
2. drag the word text to "drop here"
3. click add menu again.

I want it to appears where the first one did.

The problem with mic4ael's answer is that it moves the dragged entities as well. seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/u6xboaax/1/

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What exactly do you mean by _"These divs are draggable, so there is no div in the dropbox anymore."_?...

Comment: Is not clear what do you want to achieve, what do you mean with the same position?

Comment: let me jsfiddle it real quick

Comment: @bart2puck Is my answer also sufficient for earning the bounty or should I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [**jQuery sortable**](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) instead?

IMO, this gives a much cleaner result and it automatically takes care of your issue:

[image: sortable demo]

This can be achieved with minimal HTML and jQuery:

### HTML

```
<input type='button' id='addMenu' name='addMenu' value='Add Item'>
<div id="dropbox">
     <ul id="list1" class="list">
     </ul>
</div>
<div id='dest'>
     <ul id="list2" class="list">
         <li>Add your items here</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
var c = 0;
$('#addMenu').click(function() {
    c++;
    $("#list1").append("<li><div class='draggable item'>Draggable "+c+"</div></li>"); 
});
$( "#list1, #list2" ).sortable({
    helper: 'clone',
    opacity: 0.5,
    cursor: "move",
    connectWith: ".list",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.appendTo("#list2");
    }
});
$( "#list1,#list2" ).disableSelection();
```

## [> DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/km854v2e/)

Answer (score 1):

Is `$('#dropbox').prepend(div)` the thing that you are looking for?

Update:

```
<div id='dropbox'>
    <span id="mark">i want each new div to appear here</span>
</div>

$('#addMenu').click(function () {
    var newDiv = "<div class='yes'>Text</div>";
    $(newDiv).insertAfter('#dropbox > #mark');
    $('.yes').draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
    });
});
$('#dest').droppable();
```

Comment: no, because all that does it push the old created div down below the new one. (i didnt ding you ;) )

Comment: No idea, it would be nice if anyone who did that gave at least an explanation for it.

Comment: @bart2puck, maybe you could clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yea i am trying, its a ton of code, trying to parse out the stuff that matters.

Comment: maybe because of what i said.  i dont know though.

Comment: You can have a look at the updated version of my answer.

Comment: That kinda works.  it still adds another row to the dropbox div though.

Comment: @bart2puck _"it still adds another row to the dropbox div though."_ http://jsfiddle.net/u6xboaax/2/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this **[code on http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/marson/L02dd4xp/)** answer your question ?

I set `position:absolute` attribute to `div.yes` (on CSS section).
I also set `bottom-margin` property of `#dropbox` so that the newly created `div.yes` won't be located inside `#dest`.

Hope this helps.